# Exercise 3.4.3 in David Marker's "Model Theory"

Tags: model-theory, quantifier-elimination

While studying Model Theory for my exam, I came across the following question:

> a) Show that the theory of $(\mathbb{Z}, s)$ has quantifier elimination where $s(x) = x + 1.$
>
> b) Show that the theory of $(\mathbb{N}, s)$ does not have quantifier elimination.

I am not even sure that I understand what the theory is to be honest. I assume that I am not allowed to use $+$, $1$, etc. In that case, I don't know how to approach to the question. I tried to understand intuitively the difference between two theories and why one would have QE and the other does not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) "I am not even sure that I understand what the theory is to be honest." Well, that's a problem. Do you know what is meant by "the theory of $M$", where $M$ is an $L$-structure? (2) What techniques do you know to prove that a theory has QE?

Comment: Isn't a theory just sets of sentences in a language? For quantifier elimination, İ know that if a theory has algebraically prime models and if two models $M, N$ where M is a substructure of N implies $M <_s N$, then theory has QE.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, oh and obviously, we can just take any formula $\phi$ with free variables and find a quantifier free formula as in the definition. I think this is more applicable than the method in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, a theory is just a set of sentences. But, for example, *the* theory of $(\mathbb{Z},s)$ is the set of *all* sentences in the language $L = \{s\}$ which are true in the structure $(\mathbb{Z},s)$.

Comment: Okay, I can see that. For example, would this be a sentence in this theory  $\phi: \exists x (s(x) = 1)$

Comment: No, because $1$ is not a constant symbol in the language. On the other hand, $\forall y\, \exists x\, (s(x) = y)$ is a sentence in $\text{Th}(\mathbb{Z},s)$.

Comment: You actually can use your criterion about algebraically prime models here, because it turns out that every model of $T_\forall$ is a model of $T$, so $T$ has algebraically prime models rather trivially. But that fact isn't completely obvious, it takes a little work. It's probably easier to answer (a) by applying Marker's Corollary 3.1.6 directly. Noah's answer provides good hints for (b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain what the question is asking, and then give a hint as to how to approach it.

---

The theories in question are the theories of the structures. A theory in a language $\Sigma$ is, as you say, just a set of $\Sigma$-sentences (some authors also require that it be "deductively closed"). But each structure $\mathcal{M}$ in a language $\Sigma$ has a particular theory associated to it - its "full" theory, the set of all sentences true in the structure: $$Th(\mathcal{M})=\{\varphi: \mathcal{M}\models\varphi\}.$$ The theory of a structure is always complete (since for each structure $\mathcal{M}$ and each sentence $\varphi$ we either have $\mathcal{M}\models \varphi$ or $\mathcal{M}\models\neg\varphi$). In fact, theories of structures are *exactly* the complete theories: if $T$ is complete, then for each $\mathcal{M}\models T$ we have $Th(\mathcal{M})=T$.

---

Now let's think about the two structures in question here, $\mathcal{Z}=(\mathbb{Z}; s)$ and $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N}; s)$. The first thing to note is that their theories are not *too* different - e.g. both $Th(\mathcal{Z})$ and $Th(\mathcal{N})$ contain the sentence $$\forall x(\neg(s(x)=x)).$$ On the other hand, there is one striking difference between the two structures: $\mathcal{Z}$ "goes to infinity in both directions" but $\mathcal{N}$ "has a beginning."

- Can you go from that observation to finding a *specific sentence* $\varphi$ which is in $Th(\mathcal{Z})$ but not in $Th(\mathcal{N})$? *HINT: what makes $0$ special, in terms of the successor operation?*
- You can turn that sentence into a formula which defines $\{0\}$ in $\mathcal{N}$; this formula will have a quantifier in it. To show that $\mathcal{N}$ doesn't have quantifier elimination, it will be enough to show that $\{0\}$ is **not** definable by a quantifier-free formula.
- Finally, you'll need to show that $Th(\mathcal{Z})$ **does** have quantifier elimination. But once you understand what $Th(\mathcal{Z})$ is, per the above section, this should fit the pattern of the examples of quantifier elimination you've already seen.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit about how to prove that the theory of $(\Bbb Z, s)$ has quantifier elimination please? I am not quite sure what to do here...